# Custom binding, with binding & init - knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

We're using knockout for a SPA consisting of multiple view models, to handle what view be visible we have wrapped the divs where we bind the 'sub' view models in [with bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html).

The problem we're seeing is that when a views visibility is toggled, the Custom bindings inside it are executed, both init & update, every time.

This causes a problem for us when we have a binding based on this [jqdialog binding](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Gt5Hw/) and on each init a new dialog is created and appended to our DOM but we have no simple way of knowing when it should be removed.

More or less it's a question about if we should rearrange this part of our arcitecture or if something is missing in our binding.

Simple view:

```
<div id="view">
  <button data-bind="click: on">On</button>
  <button data-bind="click: off">Off</button>

  <div data-bind="with: visible">
    <span data-bind="foo: ''">foo</span>
    visible
  </div>

</div>​​​​​​​​​​
```

Js:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foo= {
  init: function() {
    alert("init");
  },
  update: function() {
    alert("update");
  }
}


var vm =(function() {
  var self = this;
  self.visible = ko.observable(false);

  self.on = function() { self.visible(true); };
  self.off= function() {self.visible(false); };

})();

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("view"));
```

​

A small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnhMV/6/) roughly showing our error.

Comment: You fiddle seems to be missing the actual part you are asking about! I updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnhMV/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not toggling the visibility. When you use `with` you are removing and reinserting the same elements into the DOM each time. This, of course, causes the binding to be recreated and the `init` function to fire again.

If you just want to hide/show, use the visible binding instead.

So if you do this:

```
<div data-bind="visible: visible">
    <span data-bind="foo: ''">foo</span>
    visible
</div>
```

You'll see you binding initializes when the page loads and doesn't get initialized again as you show/hide. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnhMV/8/).

Comment: Yes, we're using with instead of visible to keep the size of our dom smaller

Comment: @FredrikLeijon: Then I'm not sure there's a way around it. If you are recreating parts of the DOM, then you have to recreate the bindings.